# Not register removed child object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I´m working on a inventory system for Unity 3D. 
After I have destroyed the child object I want to check if it´s still there.

Problem: When I run the program it doesn't directly register that the child has been removed. Are the some one else out there with the same problem?

Code Add health:

Slot1Child = slot1.transform.childCount;
           public bool Slot1 = true;

```
        if (Slot1Child == 0 & Slot1 == false)
        {

            Slot1 = true;
            Debug.Log("slot 1 is empty");
            break;
        }
```

And it´s call from this function:

```
    FindObjectOfType<Health>().SetHealthPus();
    Destroy(gameObject);
    FindObjectOfType<Inventory>().InventoryReset();
```

When the player picks up any item the Slot1 is set to True and Slot1Child is set to the amount of children the slot have(in this case its only one). 
The problem is that Slot1Child do not change before i run the if comand.

Thk for help.

Comment: Destroy is not immediate

Comment: In general you would be better storing the items in a list and operate on that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try using a courutine to destroy then wait, then call a function that first checks if there are any children at all in the 'transform' because later you may have multiple diferet slots... then if there are still children check them to see if the une name health is in there... you can just use the first if[ if(transform.childCount > 0) ] if you dont have multiple slots

```
private IEnumerator DestroyThenWait(float waitTime){ 
       Destroy(gameObject);
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
       CheckSlot();
    }
public void CheckSlot(){
 if(transform.childCount > 0) //there is a child
 {
   for (var child : Transform in transform) {
    // do whatever you want with each child transform here
    // if your have multiple slots check if the health slot is among them
       if(child.name == "health"{
             //child with name health hasnt been removed maybe destroy again?
        }else{
             //child with name health has beed removed
           }
        }
 }else{
    //there is no children, every thing removed
 }
}
```

**How to call:**

```
FindObjectOfType<Health>().SetHealthPus();
coroutine = DestroyThenWait(0.3f);//Set time to a third of a second enougth time to destroy
StartCoroutine(coroutine);
FindObjectOfType<Inventory>().InventoryReset();
```

Comment: Thk for the help. It dined solve the problem but when I look back at the question I see that I could have ben more clear. The solution have given me a idea for what to do

Comment: Instead of waiting for a fixed time it should be enough to wait for only exactly one frame via `yield return null;`

Comment: Yes ot bettet to just wait one frame... Takes less resources